# Displaying selected item in listbox upon changing selected index || scrolling ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I have a Listbox with Books displayed in them. The `SelectedIndex` and `Currentindex` are bound to Properties in the Viewmodel. Underneeth the ListBox are two buttons, that simple add (next) or substract (last) one from the `SelectedIndex` Property in the Viewmodel.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Books, Mode=OneWay}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentBook, Mode=TwoWay}" 
             SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
             />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Button Content="Last" Command="{Binding ChangeBook}" CommandParameter="last"/>
        <Button Content="Next" Command="{Binding ChangeBook}" CommandParameter="next"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Hitting the `Next` and `Last` button changes the Index of the ListBox. What doesn't happen is, that when Index wonders off out of the visible area to the user, the ListBox does not scroll down, keeping the selected index visible.

I was wondering how to achive, that the SelectedItem is always visible in the ListBox, unless the user scrolls away.
Ofcourse i want do do this and not break the MVVM Pattern while dooing so.